# read from an uploaded file

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I'm using this code to upload a text file

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$error = $_FILES['file']['error'];

if (isset ($name)) {
    if (!empty($name)) {

    $location = 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/';

    if  (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)){
        echo 'File Uploaded';    
        }

        } else {
          echo 'please choose a file';
          }
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

then I have this code to read the content of a file line by line

```
<?php

    $lines = file ('the_name_of_file.txt');
    foreach ($lines as $name){
        echo "$name <br>";

    }

?>
```

how can I use the second code to read from an uploaded file?

Comment: use `fopen` to read local files

Comment: `$lines = file ( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if  (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)){
     $lines = file ($location.$name);
     foreach ($lines as $name){
       echo "$name <br>";

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To read from the already uploaded file, you need to read from the directory you uploaded to.

```
<?php
    $location = 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/';
    $lines = file($location . 'the_name_of_file.txt');
    foreach ($lines as $name) {
        // Code here
    }
?>
```